# usbmount not working with MountFlags=shared on newer kernel

Tags: debian, raspbian, usb-drive

On the Raspbian Stretch, usbmount can be made to work by changing 
 the `MountFlags` option in `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service` from `slave` to `shared`.

On Raspbian Buster (Kernel 4.19.58-v7l+), the `MountFlags` option has been removed from the service file, despite adding it back in as `shared`, usbmount no longer works. I have also set `PrivateMounts=no` without success.

I have also tried using udev-media-automount without success.

I am using the 'lite' version of Raspbian, so the regular graphical auto-mounting is not available. What is the best solution to automatically mount and unmount USB drives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like `PrivateMounts` now defaults to `yes`.

This fixed it for me:

```
sudo systemctl edit systemd-udevd
```

Add the following to the service:

```
[Service]
PrivateMounts=no
```

Then restart `udevd`:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-udevd
```

Now `usbmount` works again for me (drives are mounted to `/media/usb*` as expected).

---

Answer credit: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100375/45183

Further reading: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/9873

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of usbmount (0.24) works without modifying service files out of the box.

https://github.com/rbrito/usbmount/issues/25#issuecomment-517643716

Unfortunately, at the time of writing this, 0.24 is only available on GitHub.